# Adminscripts folder is missing in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7

I have IIS 7 installed on windows 2008 server. I want to execute commands adsutil.vbs for compression but adminscripts directory is missing under inetpub directory. How can I execute those commands ?

Answer (score 37):

In IIS7 those administration scripts are an optional component - make sure that you have the following installed:

> IIS > Web Management Tools > IIS 6 Management Capability > IIS 6 Scripting Tools

Answer (score 3):

You could also consider using the new utility AppCmd.exe included with IIS 7. Here is an article that explains how to enable HTTP Compression using AppCmd.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930909

More info on AppCmd
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772200(v=ws.10).aspx

Thanks!